# Не работает Twitter в Dolphin Anty

Tags: proxy, браузер, twitter

Всем привет, у меня проблема с антидетект браузером

Не открывается сайт Твиттера, хотя другие сервисы работают в обычном режиме.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]